# in an IIS web app, how do I get the windows user name? - not the process username

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have inherited an old asp.net web app. Part of the login process is intended to collect the windows username (not the process username).  This used to work (years ago) but a new compile of the system returns the App Pool name / username instead of the windows username.

The username is collected before authentication by the website, originally using `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`
I have tried all the other options that have been suggested with no change in the results.

```
string loginName;
loginName = Environment.UserName;
loginName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
loginName = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.UserName;
loginName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
loginName = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.SamAccountName;
loginName = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.UserPrincipalName;
```

I tried these one at a time (not all together) and in the target environment only ever got the App Pool name or App Pool username.
I have tried every combination of Authentication in IIS, the only one that makes a difference is ASP.NET impersonation which changes from App Pool name to impersonation user name.

On my local PC, launched out of Visual Studio, they all work to return the windows logged in username.

I'm quite new to asp.net web apps, and I don't know what else to try.

Comment: WebForms developers should use "`Form.User`.

Comment: Make sure `Anonymous Authentication` is disabled in `IIS`

Comment: That is the only authentication I have active.  If I remove that the page doesn't render.

Comment: I'm working in the Page_Load event of a .aspx page, the Form object is available but has no .User component. There is a Form.Page.User.Identity.Name option - but that seems to be an authenticated user - and we are not up to that yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have stumbled on the answer. If you want the server to automatically know the windows user, that windows user's credentials need to be passed to the application. If you use the Kerberos or NTML authentication options (Windows Authentication) that set of credentials is passed automatically. Otherwise you need to prompt the user to enter credentials. You don't have to use impersonation, but you can programmatically impersonate the logged in user if your app pool user has sufficient access to the dc catalog. More on that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff647405(v=pandp.10)#impersonating-the-original-caller-programmatically

Comment: In this case, it turns out that to get the windows user name, I needed to give one aspx page ONLY the windows authentication and the rest of the site anonymous authentication only.
That page acts as a kind of "gatekeeper" that lets windows authenticated users access the site by setting a session token/cookie with their user id from the database - if if gets through the "gate".

Comment: That's great Trevor! You can now use this as a single sign on service within your enterprise!

Comment: I'm giving Lev my vote because his solution would work.  Just turns out I don't need a solution that complex!